# Using my View Controller in a storyboard based app in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uistoryboard, controllers

So I have made a storyboard based app on Xcode, basically a series of table views which lead to text based pages, but I started from a blank application.

I have now written my own view controller which essentially just puts banner ads along the top, but how do I go about actually including it in my build?

I have made an objective-c class called 'viewController' based on this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

I am not sure how to run this when I build though

This is what I have so far:
http://pastebin.com/p93uSN8c

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show that in order to get help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking to add a UIViewcontroller to the storyboard.
Just open the storyboard drag and drop the UIVIEW Controller in the storyboard now,change the class name of the UIVIEW controller to the name which you have given to your view controller class.

**If you have any query plz ask and elaborate your question**

Comment: I might be going about this wrong, but I made a navigatble app based in storyboard, but there was no view controller, only the app delegates. I then followed this pages tutorial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals and made a new objective c class for it. So now I have viewController.h and viewController.m which are essentially the same as in that link, but I am not sure how to run those scripts when I build

Comment: Just drag and drop UINAVIGATION CONTROLLER and then delete the UITABLEVIEW CONTROLLER from it and drag and drop UIVIEW CONTROLLER on same storyboard nOW, you have to view one is navigation and another it View Controller .NOW ,attach the Navigation controller with the UIVIEW Controller with the root view controller.NOw change the class of UIVIEW Controller to your class name . If you have any query plz ask

Comment: Thanks, I have done this now, but how do I connect this to the start of my storyboard? I tried control dragging the view controller to my first page, but when i do this, i do a push segue and it doesn't build properly

Comment: Just select the NAVIGATION CONTROLLER and make it IS INTIAL VIEW CONTROLLER at the property of it .IT will became your main page to open .IF my answers work for it then make +1 for my answer.